# Cómo conseguir las fotos asi?

Tags: latex

¿Alguien sabe como poner las fotos como enseño abajo?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero ponerlo como sale en la foto, con (a), (b), (c) y también cambiar el nombre de Figure por Figura en español. Gracias !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poder poner las fotos así puedes usar el paquete `subcaption` y para cambiar Figure por Figura, el paquete `babel` indicándole como opción que lo quieres en castellano. El código queda de la siguiente forma:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % Cambia el idioma a español
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}     % Permite añadir subfiguras

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Caption a}
            \label{fig:labelA}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{Caption b}
            \label{fig:labelB}
        \end{subfigure}
        \newline             % Añado nueva línea para posicionar la foto c abajo
        \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
            \caption{Caption c}
            \label{fig:labelC}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Caption general}
        \label{fig:labelGeneral}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡¡¡ Mil gracias por contestar tan rapido , eres mi salvador !!!